# Gap between wall flange and cement board

Tags: tile

I know that it is recommended that a (shower and such) flange rests againts cementboard but that would result in my flange raised above the tile more that I'd like so I decided to tuck the flange into the cementboard so that, in the end, it is more flush with the tile. As a result, I have a small gap  between the flange and the cementboard, about 1/8" on average.

[image]

I did all the prep work but will be outsourcing the tile work. My question is, will the tile guy be able to work with this gap as is and still get the tile to go up to the flange (then maybe caulk or grout around) or should I reinforce it with mash tape and fill it with something like thinset or some product that comes in a caulking tube? I do have the luxury of access from the back (which is where my utiliy room is) and could reach to set mesh on that side.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might have installed the valve too deep in the wall.

The tile goes behind the silver escutcheon and up to the gray plastic circle that you can see from behind.

Usually the face of the gray circle template is at the same plane as the face of the finished tile. What kind of rough in valve is that? We can look at the instructions and it'll say.

The round hole in your backer board isn't too big, that won't be a problem. The problem looks like you recessed the valve too far into the wall, and now the tile won't slide in between the silver escutcheon and the backer board.

Comment: I already explained that I wanted the flange deep in the wall in order to be close to flush to the tile

Comment: @amphibient The tile always goes behind the silver escutcheon, it's not a matter of preference, it's the only way to install it. The back of the silver escutcheon gets silicone to the face of the tile to waterproof it. It's non-negotiable, you have to do it that way. You're expecting a tile guy to cut a perfect circle 6" in diameter, which is almost impossible.

Comment: I [fixed it](http://imgur.com/gallery/SRYW5rQ)

Answer (score 1):

That is not how it works and the trim goes over the tile for leaks and the tile installation would be easier.